# How to delete specific 'clicked' item from local Storage?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I'm not able to remove a specific item from an album list inside the local storage.
It removes one from the beginning and not the one clicked by the user.

```
function deleteRow() {
    
     document.querySelectorAll('button.delete').forEach(function (btn) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
                let albumList = []
                albumList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Album'));

                const item = albumList.map((item) => { return item })
                delete albumList.splice(item, 1);

                localStorage.setItem('Album', JSON.stringify(albumList))

        }); 
    });
}
```

I've tried to loop all the items and use splice but ends up removing 10 items instead of one.

```
function deleteRow() {
    
        document.querySelectorAll('button.delete').forEach(function (btn) {
          btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
                let albumList = []
                albumList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Album'));

                albumList.forEach((item, index) => { 
                    albumList.splice(item[index], 1);
                })
                
                localStorage.setItem('Album', JSON.stringify(albumList))

        }); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`splice` expects an index, but `map` returns an array

use `findIndex` instead

```
const item = albumList.findIndex((item) => /* your condition here */)
albumList.splice(item, 1);
```